# How to manipulate dataType xml when using $.ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax

I am having some difficulties with the XML dataype when using `$.ajax`.

I created a PHP file (`test.php`):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php        
   //this code will show some xml tag when there is an ajax call 
   if(isset($_REQUEST['t']) && $_REQUEST['t']==1){
      echo "<result >";
      echo "<info>Tristan Jun</info>";
      echo "<age>22</age>";
      echo "</result>";
      return;
    }
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#testing').click(function(){
        alert('uuuuuuu');
        var content = $.ajax({
           type:"GET",
           url :"test.php",
                   data:'t=1',
           dataType:"**html**",
           async:false,
           success:function(content){           
                cont = $(content);
                inf     = cont.find('info').text();
                age = cont.find('agel').text();
            //alert('inf');
                $('#show1').html(inf);
                $('#show2').html(total);
           },
           error: function(){
                alert('THERE'S AN ERROR');
           }
         }).**responseHTML**;
      });//end of click
 });//end of ready
 </script>

 <a id="testing" href="#">TEST</a>

 <div id="show1"></div>
 <div id="show2" style="background-color:#069"></div>
```

Here is my description for this example:

- When i click the 'TEST' button, it will call the AJAX to show the result of the PHP code
- In the AJAX call I only want to show the text of each tag in 2 `<div>` below (`#show1`, `#show2`)

The above example is using dataType HTML in `$.ajax` and it work well for this type. But when I tried with dataType XML, it didn't show anything.

So, I hope you guys give me some ideas or some references about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the whole code you've posted is the content of test.php, the response can't be valid xml.

The output will end with `<result/>` , but start's with a `<script/>` .
(XML needs to have one root-element).

I would suggest to use the output_buffer, if the request comes via ajax discard the contents of the buffer before echoing the xml.(Or just put the  PHP-code at the top )

Comment: yay !!, thanks alot. It's work perfectly :D. I forgot the structure of a xml ^^